# Looking for a source of narration of Bilal being an advocate for a marriage candidate!

Tags: source-identification, authenticity, sahaba

In one of the lessons of sheikh 'Omar Abdulkafy I witnessed around 17-20 years ago he narrated a story for which I'm looking for both source and authenticity:

The story is about a Muslim man (It seems he was a tabi'y) who wanted to get married and asked the sahabi Bilal ibn abi Rabah () to help him by going to the father of the designated bride (wife) and ask for the hand of his daughter and act as an advocate for him.
Now what in fact happened was that instead of speaking bloomy about that man Bilal told the father the rather "harsh" truth about him which made this man blush in front of his to-be father in low.
Nevertheless the man married his daughter to this candidate saying something like a person who has a sahibi such as Bilal as an advocate can't be that bad.

Note maybe I've added some wrong interpretation as I've heard the story long ago. So basically what I'm looking for is a story as described in the title beside the fact that Bilal didn't speak bloomy about the candidate.

**EDIT:**
What I could find so far myself is a story implying that Bilal in fact asked for himself and his Brother for two spouses saying to their father: "I'm Bilal and this is my Brother, two slaves from Abyssinia, who were misguided, until Allah guided us, and we were two slaves until Allah set us free, if you married us, then all praise belongs to Allah, if you rejected us then Allah is the greatest"

> ذهب يوما، رضي الله عنه، يخطب لنفسه ولأخيه زوجتين فقال لأبيهما أنا بلال وهذا أخي، عبدان من الحبشة، كنا ضالين فهدانا الله، وكنا عبدين فأعتقنا الله، أن تزوجونا فالحمد لله، وان تمنعونا فالله أكبر

I'm honestly not sure whether this is what I've heard or not, but I'd appreciate a source for that and a qualifiacation about the authenticity of the story.